# How to reattach door handle where wood behind has deteriorated?

Tags: doorknob, wood-filler

More door handle fun. So our apartment inside front door handle has fallen off as all 3 screws fell out. You can see the mess they were screwed into below:

[image: Door handle cavity]

I need to put this back on in the same place.

What would be the recommended course of action here?

- wood filler? Seems like a lot of space to fill, and it could jam the spindle.

  - dowels? But there’s no clear screw holes to position in
  - rawl plugs? Same concern as above
  - mount a new piece of wood and pull the shingle through, attach with small screws?
  - regret ever attempting to fix - attach handle on a use by use basis

More pictures:

[image: More photos]

[image: More photos]

[image]

Comment: What's on the other side?

Comment: Added some more photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill though and use [sex bolts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_bolt)  or machine screws and internally threaded tube to connect the two door knobs

Answer (score 2):

Traditional mortice door knobs were attached with grub screws to tapped holes in the spindles, so the force of pulling acted on the knob on the other side of the door, not the small screws holding the rose on. If you can replace with this sort of knob.